# MIP start in cplex using Java

Tags: cplex, java

When I am reading an "lp" file for the problem and using a MIP start reading from a "sol" file it works.

But when I pass on the same model directly to cplex (without writing lp) and try to read the solve file it says it can't find the "sol" file.

Why is there a difference? Passing the model works ok by itself. It's only passing the model to cplex directly and reading a "sol" file. between the "lp" file is created by cplex equation only and the "sol" file is the solution from binary relaxed option.

Comment: When you create the model in code and pass it to CPLEX, do you name the variables the same way that they were named in the LP file?

Comment: yes, the variable names are same, infact i created the lp file from the output function of cplex.

Comment: It might help to show relevant elements of your code and the exact error message you get.